# Android Unable to instantiate Activity(Using File Inputs)

Tags: java, android

Info: I am a decent java developer, I know my way around it pretty well I think, so I decided to give android a chance, and it hasn't been the smoothest road for me. I mess up very often. Anyway to my question if anyone would be so kind to help me out with this error I would very much appreciate it! Thank you.

Main Class

```
package dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner;

import java.io.File;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private String m_Text = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    if(firstTime()){
        GenerateNeededFiles();
    }
    else{
        //do nothing
    }
    ActionBar.TabListener tablistener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            switch(tab.getText().toString()){
            case "Lists":
                openLists();
                break;
            case "Store":
                openStore();
            case "Home":
                openTab();


            }

        }

        private void openTab() {


        }

        private void openStore() {
            View v = new View(MainActivity.this);
            v.setVisibility(1);
            v.clearFocus();
            v.bringToFront();

        }

        private void openLists() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,List_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);


        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // do nothing

        }
    };

        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Home").setTabListener(tablistener));
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Store").setTabListener(tablistener));
           actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Lists").setTabListener(tablistener));


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

private boolean firstTime() {
    File storelist = new File(this.getFilesDir()  + "\\StoreList.txt");
    File listnames = new File(this.getFilesDir()  + "\\ListNames.txt");
    if(storelist.exists() && listnames.exists()){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

private void GenerateNeededFiles() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Install_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.action_search:
    openSearch();
    return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        openSettings();
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void openSettings() {


}

private void openSearch() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Search");

    // Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_Text = input.getText().toString();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();

}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

The Class that gets an error when called

```
package dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class List_Activity extends ListActivity {
String ListNames[] = getListNames();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem ,  ListNames));

}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int pos,long id){
    this.onListItemClick(lv, v, pos, id);
    ShoppingList list = new ShoppingList(ListNames[pos]);
    try {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem,       list.toArray(list.getFile())));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private String[] getListNames() {
    File file = new File(this.getFilesDir() + "\\listnames.txt");  
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(fis); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
    String line;
    String names[] = new String[100];
    int i = 0;
    try {
        while(true){
            line = br.readLine();
            if(line == null){
                break;
            }
            else{
            try{
            names[i] = line;
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return names;
}

}
```

and here is the printStack

```
03-23 04:58:16.523: D/dalvikvm(3710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 151K, 18% free 2770K/3356K, paused 2ms, total 7ms
03-23 04:58:16.531: D/dalvikvm(3710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 100K, 19% free 2988K/3680K, paused 1ms, total 4ms
03-23 04:58:16.535: I/dalvikvm-heap(3710): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.414MB for 1127532-byte allocation
03-23 04:58:16.539: D/dalvikvm(3710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 4089K/4784K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
03-23 04:58:16.555: D/dalvikvm(3710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 4089K/4784K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
03-23 04:58:16.587: I/dalvikvm-heap(3710): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.833MB for 2536932-byte allocation
03-23 04:58:16.599: D/dalvikvm(3710): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 6567K/7264K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
03-23 04:58:16.615: D/HardwareRenderer(3710): Profiling hardware renderer
03-23 04:58:16.647: D/libEGL(3710): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
03-23 04:58:16.651: D/(3710): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb85b3b40, tid 3710
03-23 04:58:16.655: D/libEGL(3710): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
03-23 04:58:16.655: D/libEGL(3710): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
03-23 04:58:16.711: W/EGL_genymotion(3710): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-23 04:58:16.711: E/OpenGLRenderer(3710): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
03-23 04:58:16.723: E/OpenGLRenderer(3710): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
03-23 04:58:16.723: D/OpenGLRenderer(3710): Enabling debug mode 0
03-23 04:58:18.015: D/AndroidRuntime(3710): Shutting down VM
03-23 04:58:18.015: W/dalvikvm(3710): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bae648)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner/dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner.List_Activity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:199)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner.List_Activity.getListNames(List_Activity.java:38)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at dev.shaw.MyShoppingPlanner.List_Activity.<init>(List_Activity.java:16)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
03-23 04:58:18.015: E/AndroidRuntime(3710):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: you are trying to get Context of Activity before onCreate. use `ListNames[] = getListNames();` inside onCreate method of Activity

Comment: Thanks, I honestly have no clue how I missed that.